# getting logout on router V6 using <Outlet/> and useEffect to get jwt on refreshing

Tags: react-hooks, react-router

i think i'm missing some theory here cause i cant get the axios call that verifies jwt token to happen before the auth state goes back to its initial state which is null, therefore page logouts on refreshing.
i know axios is asynchronous but returning <outlet/ > and <navigate/ > within the verify function returns nothing.

PrivateRoutes.js

```
const PrivateRoutes = () => {
const { auth, setAuth } = useContext(AuthContext);  // authentication state

const verify = async () => {
Axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
const res = await Axios.get("http://localhost:3001/verify");

const data = res.data;
console.log("data from jwt", data);
setAuth({
  logged: data.logged,
  id: data.user_id,
  name: data.name,
  });
};

useEffect(() => {
verify();
 }, []);

 console.log("private", auth);

 return auth.logged ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to="/login" />;
 };

 export default PrivateRoutes;
```

on console i get this order on refreshing.

console

```
private {logged: null, name: '', id: ''}
data from jwt {id: 3, name: 'mariela', logged: true}
```

i tried this but it renders nothing

```
const PrivateRoutes = () => {
const { auth, setAuth } = useContext(AuthContext);

const verify = async () => {
Axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
const res = await Axios.get("http://localhost:3001/verify");

const data = res.data;

setAuth({
  logged: data.logged,
  id: data.usu_id,
  name: data.nombre,
});

if (data.logged) {
  return <Outlet />;
 } else {
  return <Navigate to="/login" />;
 }
};

useEffect(() => {
verify();
}, []);


};

export default PrivateRoutes;
```

Answer (score 1):

In PrivateRoutes.js file,

```
useEffect(() => {
verify();
}, []);
```

This will run once after the render, so if you want to that your `useEffect` is ran when state was null, you need assign value for the array of dependency with following:

```
useEffect(() => {
    verify();
    }, [something]);
```

So, every ttime something changes, verify function in `useEffect` will be called.

However, I think that you should call verify function in `Interceptors` of axios. I have a example: https://github.com/ImTomQ/react-jwt-auth/blob/develop/src/service/base_service.js

Reference:
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect